# 'At least one out of multiple' conditional

Tags: fish

I want to say:

```
command1
command2
command3

if not at least one of these yields status code 0, then 
launch command4
```

The goal is to always execute all of them, and in case all fail, then execute command number 4.

I tried creating a counter, and that seems not very elegant, and all different combinations with and/or, if else and so on, also look clumsy/don't work.

How would you write this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your code says  "if at least one of these statements yields status code 0, then 
launch command4" but your question says "in case all fail, then execute command number 4". Which is it – do you want to run command4 if all fail, or if at least one succeeds?

Comment: Thanks a lot about making me aware about this mistake. I correct it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it appears you do want to run them eagerly - always run all statements and only run the rest if any one of them succeeded, you'll have to use a variable:

```
set -l success 0
statement1; and set success 1
statement2; and set success 1
statement3; and set success 1

if test $success = 1
    # do your thing
end
```

---

This isn't a very common thing, typically you'd want to run it *lazily* - run until one succeded. That's "or":

```
if statement1; or statement2; or statement3
```

(also "statement" here would have to be a *command* - that's what fish's `if` expects)

For example you could do:

```
if test -e /etc/foo.conf; or test -e ~/.config/foo.conf; or test -e ~/.foo.conf
```

if you wanted to test for a config file for something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you noted yourself, does this stop with the evaluation, once it hits one positive execution? This is not what I want. The goal is to always execute all of them, and in case all fail, then execute command number 4.

Comment: In that case you will have to use a variable, yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is really helpful. To understand this fully: Why do I need to ; the command, before I add the `and` to it?

Comment: And I actually want to run the last command only when none of the above ran successfully, and your answer gave me enough insight, to figure out the answer on my own. :)

I had a typo in my question, that misled you potentially, sorry and thanks.

Comment: If you just do `command and`, that looks like the `and` is just more arguments to pass to the command. You need the `;` to tell fish that the command is done so it will start recognizing keywords again.

Comment: Ah, is that because `and` has lower precedence? Since it seems `&&` does need that

Comment: No, it's because the string "and" isn't special syntactically, while `&&` is. "and" is for the most part just an ordinary builtin. So if you do `foo and` that will pass the string "and" as an argument to "foo".

Answer (score 0):

In psudo code, you are write above logic. Is this what you are looking for?

```
status_code1 = statement1()
status_code2 = statement2()
status_code3 = statement3()

if (status_code1 == 0) or (status_code2 == 0) or (status_code3 == 0):
    # At least one of the statements yielded a status code of 0
    # Your code here
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a typo in my initial question, so the people answered a slightly different case.

Thanks to [faho's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77273182/6712414) was I able to infer the answer myself:

```
   set -l success no

   command1; and set success yes
   command2; and set success yes
   command3; and set success yes

   if test $success = no
      command4
   end
```

Very easy, if you know how :D